# How can I fix DAT file problem (binary type) with python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I have a problem with my (dot).Dat file. My .Dat file type is a binary file, I need it to match with ground truth with the same type file.  I have some image input [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FSzF.png).

The problem is when I save it to DAT file and try to open at ICDAR 2013 application who I get from this site [http://users.iit.demokritos.gr/~nstam/ICDAR2013HandSegmCont/resources.html](http://users.iit.demokritos.gr/%7Enstam/ICDAR2013HandSegmCont/resources.html),

- The result is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDNWd.jpg) (ignore black and white color). The result I get like GT DAT file become two images in one image.
- Whereas the result that I want is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdlDU.jpg) (this is GT DAT file).  I think this problem related to a header image, but when I try to find out, the header looks same with my result.

> Input image from png file
> b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x06\xe4'
>
> My DAT file
> b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>
> GT DAT file
> b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

I try to find it with python code as follows

```
import numpy as np

print ("input image from png file")
binary_data = open('10-result.png','rb').read(20)
print(binary_data)

print ("my DAT file")
binary_data = open('gt.dat','rb').read(20)
print(binary_data)

print ("GT DAT file")
binary_data = open('sample.dat','rb').read(20)
print(binary_data)
```

Does anyone know what is the real problem with my result?

==Edited==

My result and GT file can see at https://drive.google.com/open?id=14REtgVPr-M3GUfRoYGV2pD8EOs4-WIV-

Comment: Sorry, I'd love to help you but your question is REALLY DIFFICULT to understand! You seem to be showing us 20 bytes that are all zero in both cases to prove that something is different (or wrong) compared to something else. Please try just short simple sentences. *"This is my image file - it is 32 pixels wide and 84 pixels high and there are 3 RGB bytes per pixel. It should look like this. But it looks like this."*

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you for the reply. Sorry if my question is not clear for you, but what I mean is that my result is not like GT DAT file (it's like two manuscript images are reduced in size and are in one image), meanwhile input image that I used is only one manuscript. I don't understand why that happened?

Comment: You have provided links to a PNG file and 2 JPEG files. Where's the GT DAT file please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have added a link to see my result and GT DAT file

Comment: Ok, your `GT.dat` file is 15748992 bytes and your input image is 1764x248 pixels, i.e. 437472 pixels. So you have exactly 36 bytes per pixel. I have heard of 1 byte per pixel (greyscale or palette), 3 bytes per pixel (RGB), 4 bytes per pixel (float or RGBA) and 6 and 8 bpp, but never 36. So maybe you could say what the 36 bytes per pixel are please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry I do not understand why you can get value 36 bytes per pixel, can you tell me why it can be like that? Btw My input image is the output process from color image->grayscale->binarization->resizing(become smaller)->coloring per line->resizing(to original size), and this result used as input to convert it become DAT file format. I didn't know why it became 36 bytes per pixel as you said..

Comment: I have no idea! I presume you wrote the code that creates the file, or somebody gave you the file telling you what was in it. I know neither of those things and therefore have no chance of working out how to extract the correct image.